# How to group data by age range?

Tags: google-sheets

Given data list with two columns: 'Division' and 'Age.'

```
username       year_of_birth
Albert Albo    1977
Bob Bilo       1974
Conan Cornic   1989
Don Duan       1954
Etan Etin      1967
Fabio Forio    1976
```

I want to put this data into a Pivot Table and group the ages into specified ranges; however, I'm having issues figuring out how to get around grouping them into set increments that don't vary.  My first range would need to be 18-24, my next would be 25-29, then 30-34, 35-39, and so on until I hit 64. Then, I would have 65+ all grouped into one, like so:

[image: Custom Age Ranges]

**How could I make it work ?**

Answer (score 2):

A simpler (also single formula) might be:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(year(now())-B2:B+1,Larry,2))
```

where year of birth is in ColumnB. This though does require a named range (`Larry`) of:

[image: Lookup array]

This repeats the assumption that, wanting month, day, time, everyone is treated as having been born at the very start of the `year_of_birth`.

A contingency is included for under 18s where `0-17` in the array might be replaced by `invalid` or such like.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let's see if we can make it in a single formula

[image]

Creating a pivot from here is trivial.